# Centralized WebUI on node-red with multiple raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, node-red

I have a question regarding node-red, before jumping on it.
I find a big difficultly to get a home-automation tool such as node-red, to get working multiple raspberry pi nodes.

On the master I use django(brain)+angular(web-ui)+pigpio-library to interconnect the master pi with slaves.
Basically using pigpio I can send from the master `turn-on` or `turn-off` signals to slave without any other tool.

- In my home configuration, I have 3 raspberry pi.
- All 3 are connected to the same network.
- 1st pi is master and the other 2 are slaves.
- 2nd and 3rd raspberry pi are slaves, and only have pigpio service
  installed
- this give me centralized interface to n pi`s connected to my network
- downside it that our app is not yet able to do complex things:events, tasks, etc.
  So if I want to connect a PIR to my master and based on this trun on a LED on slave`s gpio, I cannot!

In node-red or home-assistant, both use mqqt to send or receive information regarding sensors or manipulate gpio`s.

Can I have with node-red a centralized interface installed ok master pi, and from there to act upon a gpio on slave pi?

thank you
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [node-red-node-pi-gpiod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-node-pi-gpiod) node on a central Node-RED instance to control GPIO pins on remote pi's.

You just need to make sure that pigpiod is configured to listen on the external interface and that the firewall will not block access.

Comment: well gpiod just need to be installed, and it just works, it very simple :)
This is how I use it right now: on the slave pi's, it`s installed on them, and the master send requests!